# Network building software

Tags: network

What I have in mind is software, where I can build network virtualy, with routers, switches, subnets etc. (maybe with some kind of checking mechanism). I want to understand concept of networking better by building some network.

I know there are some diagram tools, but thats not exactly what I have in mind.

So my question is... Is there any software, where I can emulate/build enterprise network, with some error/conflict checking?

Edit: You will probably put it on hold anyway, because as I found out....software reccomendations are not allowed here.

Comment: Do you have an actual question? Announcement of your intentions is not on-topic here, where questions get asked and answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [GNS3](https://www.gns3.com/).  Also, look at Oracles [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VirtualBox) which allows you to stand up multiple virtual routers such as Cisco's CSR 1000v or VyOS on a PC or laptop.

Comment: As you know, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: GNS3 might be what I'm looking for, I'll check it out. Thank you!